# Running a "hello world" program under CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a {};
    a = 10;
    cout << "Hello world!" << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I get error below:

```
-------------- Run: Debug in First (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /home/oem/CPlus/First/bin/Debug/First
Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:
Executing: xterm -T First -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:. /home/oem/CPlus/First/bin/Debug/First  (in /home/oem/CPlus/First/.)
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

My system is Linux mint20. g++ and gcc both are 9.3.0.

Comment: I can execute it by command line

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question.
I can use debug button.  just can't use the run button.
Tool Menu -> Setting -> Envrionment -> Terminal to lanuch console progrems (set your Terminal Console Progrem)